# Populate a dropdown from mysql and have the chosen item display in the dropdown after page refreshes

Tags: php, mysql

I am using php with a dropdown to select data and display the selected item in the dropdown after the page refreshes so have used this code which works.

```
<select name="select" id="mysort" onchange="select(this.value);">
    <option value="5"  <?php if($selecting == '5'):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>5 </option>
    <option value="6"  <?php if($selecting == '6'):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>6 </option>
    <option value="7"  <?php if($selecting == '7'):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>7 </option>
    <option value="8"  <?php if($selecting == '8'):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>8 </option>
</select>
```

I then want to be able to populate the dropdown from a mysql database. This code works:

```
$sql = "SELECT DISTINCT number FROM files ORDER BY number";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
echo '<select name="choose" id="mychoice">';
    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
          echo '<option value='.$row["number"].'>'.$row,["number"].'</option>';
        }
        echo '</select>';
    }
```

I am having trouble with the syntax when I put the two blocks of code together so that the values are populated from the mysql and the selected option displays in the dropdown after the page refreshes.
I would be grateful for any help with this.

Comment: What you're trying to do is not quite clear. Can you explain the flow in more detail? What's going wrong, are you receiving any errors?

Comment: I want to be able to combine these two lines:
    <option value="5"  <?php if($selecting == '5'):?> selected="selected"<?php endif;?>>5 </option>
and
echo '<option value='.$row6["yearlevel"].'>'.$row6["yearlevel"].'</option>';
but get php syntax errors for all the possibilities that I try.

Comment: I am still not sure what you mean by 'combine these two lines', are you trying to add more option to your select via PHP after your page has loaded? Can you include more context in your question as well as the error you are receiving? In the block of code in your question there is a syntax error, there should not be a comma in `$row,["number"]` if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this -

```
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo '<option value="'.$row["number"].'"'; 
      if($selecting == $row["number"]) { echo " selected "; }
      echo '>'.$row["number"].'</option>';
    }
```